# num = 'ps -ef | grep -v grep| grep BatchName| wc -l'

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I am having the basic knowledge of Unix. I'm programming for a wrapper script but in the above line of code I'm not getting the meaning and output of "grep -v grep". Please explain that in detail. Try to explain requested part only, it would be great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's excluding the `grep` process from the results, that's it. Run

```
grep --help
```

And you'll see

```
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
```

So the line

```
xxxx   27731 27613  0 17:21 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto /bin/bash
```

won't be returned as a result since we excluded "grep".